# Error while deploying django website on heroku .Exception Type: ProgrammingError at / Exception Value: relation "home_post" does not exist

Tags: django, heroku

I'm trying to deploy my django website on heroku. The code works fine in localhost but got the following error while deploying on heroku.

Environment:

Request Method: GET
Request URL: https://santoshach.herokuapp.com/

Django Version: 3.2
Python Version: 3.9.4

Following is my settings.py

````
```Installed Applications:
````

```
['django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
'home',
'crispy_forms']
Installed Middleware:
('whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware')
```

Following is the error I'm getting on the browser:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
   return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)

The above exception (relation "home_post" does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT COUNT(*) AS "__count" FROM "home_post" WHERE "home_po...
                                         ^
) was the direct cause of the following exception:
 File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 47, in inner
   response = get_response(request)
 File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 181, in _get_response
   response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
 File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 70, in view
   return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
 File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 98, in dispatch
   return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
 File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/views/generic/list.py", line 157, in get
   context = self.get_context_data()
 File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/views/generic/list.py", line 119, in get_context_data
   paginator, page, queryset, is_paginated = self.paginate_queryset(queryset, page_size)
 File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/views/generic/list.py", line 69, in paginate_queryset
   page = paginator.page(page_number)
 File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/paginator.py", line 76, in page
   number = self.validate_number(number)
 File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/paginator.py", line 54, in validate_number
   if number > self.num_pages:
 File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 48, in __get__
   res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
 File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/paginator.py", line 103, in num_pages
   if self.count == 0 and not self.allow_empty_first_page:
 File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 48, in __get__
   res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
 File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/paginator.py", line 97, in count
   return c()
 File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 412, in count
   return self.query.get_count(using=self.db)
 File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 526, in get_count
   number = obj.get_aggregation(using, ['__count'])['__count']
 File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 511, in get_aggregation
   result = compiler.execute_sql(SINGLE)
 File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1169, in execute_sql
   cursor.execute(sql, params)
 File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 98, in execute
   return super().execute(sql, params)
 File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 66, in execute
   return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
 File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 75, in _execute_with_wrappers
   return executor(sql, params, many, context)
 File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
   return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
 File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 90, in __exit__
   raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
 File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
   return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)

Exception Type: ProgrammingError at /
Exception Value: relation "home_post" does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT COUNT(*) AS "__count" FROM "home_post" WHERE "home_po...
                                         ^
```

Comment: Hey, did you add `python manage.py migrate` in your Procfile?